# Is there any way to get hyperlinked results from a code block in org mode?

Tags: bash, emacs, org-mode

In org mode, when you generate links from code blocks:

```sh
#+begin_src shell :results output
for f in *; do
    if [[ "$f" == "index.org" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    printf -- "- [[file:$f][$f]]\n"
done
#+end_src
```

#+RESULTS: 
: - link_one 
: - link_two 
: - link_three

Even though they don't "expand" (shown in the format [[file:link_one][link_one]]),
you still cannot interact with them in emacs as links.

For clarification, I am trying to use this on an index page to
automaticlly link in all the other pages in that directory. I think
it would look cool to do this from org mode natively instead of
writing a script to do it, and it's a more elegant solution.

This first problem can be solved by deleting the colons in the results block, but that is a pain.

Furthermore, so long as the #+RESULTS: block is there, exporting to html does not recognize
the links and instead opts to display them as plaintext, even though emacs (the editor )
"understands" that they should be links when you delete all the colons at the front of the links. In other words: the html export function doesn't
recognize them as links, even though emacs does. My question is: how can you generate links from
code blocks such that they are recognized by the exporter and by emacs automatically?

I've tried looking around but it's a very niche problem. There are ways to get links
from code blocks, but they involve writing all the output to a file, which is not what
I want. Maybe there is some hack where I can make it work by using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. Basically another post had a similar (but not the same)
problem, and their solution was to use `:results output raw` instead, which
almost worked. You also need to add `:exports both` in order for the exporter to recognize the output of the code blocks.

Comment: You probably want `:exports results` so that the code block does not clutter the output. And if you have filenames with underscores, you probably want `#+OPTIONS: ^:{}` at the top of the file, otherwise `a_b` will appear as `a` with a `b` subscript.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I like the aesthetic of having the code block visible (at least while i don't have many entries), but I will keep in mind your second suggstion.